# Python, my UPDATE mysql query needs a variable in the WHERE clause

Tags: python, mysql

I got an error:

```
[Running] python -u "c:\xampp\htdocs\python\beautiful.py"
51
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\xampp\htdocs\python\beautiful.py", line 18, in <module>
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE data SET words =" + str(wordCount) + " WHERE id = " +str(results[0]))
  File "C:\Users\bertv\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 521, in execute
    self._connection.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Users\bertv\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1059, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.906 seconds
```

in the last line of my code. It's obvious that I constructed my query in a wrong way. I'm struggling to combine or better concatenate the `WHERE id =`  with the `+str(results[0]` part. This is the code:

```
import re
import requests
import mysql.connector

db = mysql.connector.connect(
host='myHost',
user=('myUser'),
passwd=('myPassword'),
database=('myDB')
)

mycursor = db.cursor()
        
mycursor.execute("SELECT id, REPLACE(REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(`comment`, '(<[^>]*>)|(&nbsp;)', ''), '\t', ''), '\n', '') FROM data WHERE topic = 60940") 
for results in mycursor:
        wordCount = len(re.findall(r'[ \n]+', results[1]))
        print(wordCount)
        mycursor.execute("UPDATE data SET words =" + str(wordCount) + " WHERE id = " +str(results[0]))
```

How do I construct that last UPDATE query in a proper way?
`mycursor.execute("UPDATE data SET words =" + str(wordCount) + " WHERE id = " +str(results[0]))`

Comment: you need to read all results first, still´switch to prepared statements